# HTML CSS Table layout

Tags: html, css, dynamic, width, css-tables

I have a problem creating a proper table layout.

I need the table to have a specific width, with 3 columns (no problems so far).
The problem is that I need the 2nd column needs to be only the width of its content, and no bigger, and that column has to dynamically adapt to that content.

The other two should take up the rest of the width of the table.

Example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             |Here is the main text|                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: only css or js accepted ? One width for all cells of the column (2 of course) or 1 width by row ?

Comment: @kevpoccs js would be accepted but i'd like to do it with css. And there is only this one row, if you mean that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aCUsF/3/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
td {
    border:1px solid grey;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    width:1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: @DinoPrašo, the table maxes to 100% of the parent, so you may need to add `html, body{width:100%;}` for example to your CSS- or apply a width to the element the table finds itself within

Comment: @ExtPro nope, thats not the problem... the table is in a 960px wide div anyway and has 100% width already

Comment: @DinoPrašo hmm, if you can provide some HTML/CSS that'd be handy. Alternatively does your browser support `nth-child`?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out... My table had display:block; in it, that caused it not to work as it should.

Comment: @DinoPrašo great- glad you got a solution

Answer (score 1):

use colspan in html 
see fiddel @ http://jsfiddle.net/8HtZu/

```
<table style="width:100%;text-align:center;border:2px solid #800" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Title</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will do the trick

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td class="dynamic">This is some longer text</td>
    <td>some other stuff;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="dynamic">This is some longer text and longer;</td>
    <td>some other stuff</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table 
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
table td
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

td
{
    width: 33.3%;
}

td.dynamic
{
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vdFwF/

Comment: The important thing is the setting of `width` to `1px`, and the fact that in tables it is interpreted loosely as `min-width` due to old standards. Adding `table-layout:fixed` to the table, for example, would break this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse"  
bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="AutoNumber1">
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="34%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the middle column just fit with his content

Comment: The width mustn't be fixed :(
It has to be exactly the width of the content, and no pixel wider.

Comment: what do you meen with fixed?

Comment: @Yunus Well, I mean that if you do this, the width doesn't change depending on the content. It has to be the width of the content

Comment: why you do not use one td and center your content

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign  **min-height** to each **td** elements.
Try this Jfiddle.
 `JSfiddle`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse"  
bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" id="AutoNumber1">

<tr>
     <td width="100%" colspan="3">
<center>your content </center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```